# How to select img src within Tumblr xml file using php?

Tags: php, xml, image, tumblr

I am trying to select the src for the first img within the following post xml.

```
<post>
<regular-title>Testing 1</regular-title>
<regular-body>
<p>This is a test for projects on the website</p> 
<p><img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3t0r3saXy1rocfxw.jpg"/></p> 
<p><img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3t0s6bPyw1rocfxw.jpg"/></p>
</regular-body>
</post>
```

I can select the title and post text using php but I havent been able to select the img or its src.

```
$title = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-title'};
$img = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-body'}->??????;
$post = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-body'};
```

Am i using the right method to select the img or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $xml->posts->post->{'regular-body'}, $matches);
$first_img = $matches[1][0];
if(!empty($first_img))
  return $first_img;
return 'no image url.png';
```

This should work just fine for you

Answer (score 0):

You can get it easily using the [DOM classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$xml = '<post>
    <regular-title>Testing 1</regular-title>
    <regular-body>
    <p>This is a test for projects on the website</p> 
    <p><img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3t0r3saXy1rocfxw.jpg"/></p> 
    <p><img src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3t0s6bPyw1rocfxw.jpg"/></p>
    </regular-body>
    </post>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
$firstImage = $images->item(0); //get the first img tag
$src = $firstImage->getAttribute("src");
```